# C# - List of Logon Sessions

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know how to retrieve the list of users that are logged on.  I can open up Windows Task Manager and look at the Users tab and look at the users that are logged on the PC.  How do I get that list of users.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at WMI. You can use System.Management namespace:

```
 System.Management.ConnectionOptions myConnectionOptions = new System.Management.ConnectionOptions();
        myConnectionOptions.Impersonation  = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

    System.Management.ManagementScope  objwmiservice;
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher myObjectSearcher;
    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection myCollection;

    try
    {
        objwmiservice = new System.Management.ManagementScope( ("\\\\" + (HostOrIP + "\\root\\cimv2")), myConnectionOptions);
        objwmiservice.Connect();
        myObjectSearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(objwmiservice.Path.ToString(), "Select UserName from Win32_ComputerSystem");
        myObjectSearcher.Options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 7000);
        myCollection = myObjectSearcher.Get();

        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject myObject in myCollection)
        {
            if (!(myObject.GetPropertyValue("User name") == null))
            {
                string Userx = myObject.GetPropertyValue("Usernam e").ToString();
                int posx = Userx.LastIndexOf("\\");
                if ((posx > 0))
                {
                    Userx = Userx.Substring((posx + 1));
                    return Userx.ToUpper();
                }
            }
         }
         return "<Nobody>";
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
            return "<Nobody>";
     }
}
```

Which I got from [this link](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/793434.html)

Comment: Thanks.  When I'm using fast user switching and have multiple logins, this is only returning one user and that's the active on.

Comment: When run locally on a Windows 2019 server, it returns nothing.  Unfortunately, this may be a result of WMI not returning anything in the UserName field, but it doesn't work nonetheless.

Comment: Okay that is good to know. This is a 11 year old answer, btw.