# getting username from computer network name

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a list of ips that I use to get the computer names for these ips.  I was wondering if there is anyway in c# to tie the computer name to the logged in user to that computer or vice versa.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to enumerate all users that are logged in, fast-switching or terminal server, but you can use WMI and query the processes (Win32_Process) to get the owner of the explorer.exe process.  This will tell you who is actively logged into the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate sessions on each machine and pick one (or many) you like. Note that it would require box admin privileges (i.e. running as domain admin). See [C# - List of Logon Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994652/c-sharp-list-of-logon-sessions) for details.

Note that result will be many-to-many mapping.